# Convergence in $C(X)$ is uniform convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

I read this the convergence in $C(X)$ is uniform convergence.

Where $X$ is compact hausdorff topological space and

$$C(X)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{C}\;\mid \; f\ \text{is continuous}\}$$

And 
$$\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X\}$$

What I have done: I suppose $f_n\to f $ pointwise, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ and for every $x\in X$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have

$$d(f_n(x),f(x))=\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|<\varepsilon$$

then

$$\sup_{x\in X}\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|<\varepsilon$$

Then further what I should do?

Edited:My question is how to prove that convergence in C(X) is uniform convergence and also  is this because of compactness of $X$ or because of supremum norm?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Your question does not make sense: $C(X)$ is, indeed, usually endowed with the uniform convergence, but you are free to put any other topology on it (such as the weak topology or the pointwise convergence, or even the discrete or the trivial topology). It depends on what you try to do with it, there is no intrinsic topology.

Comment: @AlexM. my question is how to prove that convergence in C(X) is uniform convergence.Why this space has this property?May be it is trivial for you,as you said "C(X) is,indeed,usually enowed with uniform convergence"but i want to know why it is so in C(X) and not in other spaces.

Comment: Wait a second: how do you define $C(X)$?

Comment: X is compact hausdorff space and C(X) is the set of complex valued functions on X.

Comment: Your example is in general not true. Pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence in anyway, even if we are talking about continuous functions on compact. You need additional conditions such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C(X)$. This means $\|f_n-f\| \rightarrow 0$. In turn, this means that $\forall \epsilon >0 \space \exists n_\epsilon \space \| f_n-f \|< \epsilon$. Detailing what the norm means, we get $\mathbb{sup}_{x \in X}|f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$, which in particular implies $|f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon \space \forall x \in X$ (and $n>n_\epsilon$ as previously found, of course). And this is just the definition of the uniform convergence.